# Why does this string reversal loop alert `NaN` when adding characters to my variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to take an input string and make a reverse of that string and alert it on the screen. But I am getting `NaN` in the alert.

I am taking the input and assigning it to the variable `someText` and converting it to a reverse string using a `for` loop and assigning it to the variable `newText` and alerting the `newText` on screen.

There might be be a better way to do this, but I just strated learning JavaScript.

```html
<h2>Is this word a palindrome?</h2>
<input id="entertext" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text">
<button id="submit">Enter</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
    var someText = document.getElementById("entertext").value;
    var newText;

    for (i = someText.length; i >= 0; i--) {
      newText += someText[i];
      alert(newText);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `newText` is `undefined` at the beginning since it’s not initialized to anything. Also, your loop starts at an undefined index. There is no index `someText.length` in `someText`.

Comment: Why not step through the code in a debugger? @Xufox `undefined` + `undefined` is `NaN`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Oh, didn’t realize that the loop _starts_ at out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the character which does not exist in `someText`. Because `someText[someText.length]` is always `undefined`. It should be `i=someText.length-1`. Also `newText` should have some initial value (Empty string).

```js
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function (){
  var someText = document.getElementById("entertext").value;
  var newText='';
  for(i=someText.length-1; i>=0; i--){
      newText  += someText[i];
      alert(newText);
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Is this word a palindrome?</h2>
<input id="entertext" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text">
<button id="submit">Enter</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I messed the in length and array count.

Comment: @new2programming, may I request you to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in........thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You use `+=` on an uninitialized variable. Such a variable starts out as `undefined`. You don’t want to add things to `undefined`, so initialize it. If you expect a string, use `var newText = "";`.
2. Your loop starts at `i = someText.length`, then you access `someText[i]`. That index doesn’t exist. The indexes range from `0` to `someText.length - 1`, inclusive. See [the MDN article about indexed collections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections). Since non-existing indexes return `undefined`, this is where `undefined + undefined` is introduced which results in `NaN`.

Minor things:

- Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of assigning to the `onclick` property.
- Declare `i` to avoid making it global.

---

So either use

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var someText = document.getElementById("entertext").value;
  var newText = "";

  for(let i = someText.length - 1; i >= 0; --i){
    newText += someText[i];
    alert(newText);
  }

  alert(`Palindrome? ${newText === someText}`); // To check whether it’s a palindrome.
});
```

or, with [`Array.prototype.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse), simply

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
  const someText = document.getElementById("entertext").value;

  alert(`Palindrome? ${someText === [...someText].reverse().join("")}`);
});
```

Comment: I did trying initalizing the var, but it still didn't work at first because of not using -1 for the length. Thank you for the help.